# How to start with a DBMS project

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

We are supposed to make a web-based project using postgres. The topic is library management system, where on a website a user can search whether a book is available in the library, if it is present then where, and so on.

The problem is just that I don't know anything about web development. I do have a pretty good knowledge of sql, but I'm confused a bit in that too, because I don't know if I'll just have to run the queries in my laptop in postgres and link if it "somehow" to the website, or will I have to upload my data on some server (for eg., firebase in case Android development) to be used in my website.

So briefly, I've just two questions:-

How should I start, because I have no idea where to begin with(I do have all the data needed btw)?

About postgres, will the queries run on my laptop or some server?

Please help me with this. Some online resources for the same are way more than just welcome, because I was unable to find any. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'd take a look at some design pattern in order to learn some theory on how to make (web) apps in the right way. You can visit Martin Fowler's [web site](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/) and read them.

Once studied, you'd follow my advice. If you've got Java expetise, I'd start by learning [Spring Boot](http://spring.io/projects/spring-boot), which has every piece you need to achieve your goal. This project follows lot's of design patterns (MVC, Repository, DAO, AOP, IoC/DI...) and lets you follow others (DTO). Anyway, choose the right template engine (I like [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/)) or any other framework ([Angular 2](https://angular.io/)...).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to development world. When starting out it seems very confusing but it is not that much.

Start slow, there are many tutorials  across which helps.. just do a bit of google. 
To answer your question :

How should I start, because I have no idea where to begin with(I do have all the data needed btw)?
-- Google simple website with postgres db. For that you will require the database to be installed and a webserver on your machine. All of which will be used when you host the website

About postgres, will the queries run on my laptop or some server?
-- It will run on where you have installed the database..

hope this helps :)